# Automatically execute CreateDesktopIcon and CreateQuickLaunchIcon

Tags: inno-setup

I would like to automatically create a desktop and quick launch item for the user without having to ask him first.

I am deploying my application in a few companies only, and they all have this need.

Currently, Inno Setup shows this page where they manually have to check these 2 options, and then again on the next page they are shown that they are about to apply these 2 options.

I would therefore like to ask if it is possible to automatically set these 2 options and hide this "additional tasks" page.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just simply omit `Tasks: TaskName` and don't add the `[Tasks]` section in the script.

```
[Icons]
Name: "{commondesktop}\{#MyAppName}"; Filename: "{app}\{#MyAppExeName}"; WorkingDir: "{app}"
Name: "{userappdata}\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Quick Launch\{#MyAppName}"; Filename: "{app}\{#MyAppExeName}"; WorkingDir: "{app}"
```